# Send a React-Native (Expo) app to the background on Android back button press with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'd like to have the Android back button send the app to the background using pure JavaScript, but the only solutions I've been able to find require changes in Java and I'm trying to avoid ejecting from Expo just yet.

Is there a way to send an app to the background rather than exiting it.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler did you check this ?

Comment: @NazırDogan yes, unfortunately that only allows for exiting the app.

Answer (score -2):

Here is snack example. https://snack.expo.io/@nazrdogan/carefree-beef-jerky
When you return false from Backhandler app will go background. if return true you can do your own logic.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card, Button } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }
  handleBackPress = () => {
    //if you return false. it will goes background
    return false;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```